# Serial Communication Using ATMega128L

Tags: avr, atmega

I made a simple communication using atmega128. Is syntax for UART0 between atmega128 and atmega8535 different?
Because when i used command **"printf"** and **"putchar"** on atmega128, it didn't work, but on atmega8535 worked

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have loaded the UBRR0L and UBRR0H register with proper value, you have used the same compiler to compile both atmega128 and atmega8535, and there is no issue with the hardware which is used try to check the serial communication with direct register write operation. try to transmit single character successfully. like below

```
while(!(UCSR1A & (1 << UDRE1)));
UDR1 = 'A'; // it could be any character
```

if above code works fine then check the printf and putchar code in your compiler library, and find out how those codes are modified to write character to serial port! if needed modify that printf and putchar code to suit atmega128. mmake sure that while modifying you keep the original code safer!

Answer (score 1):

As Basavaraju pointed out, try to keep it simple for initial testing.

Some general potential problems that come to mind:

- Clock frequency and UBRR calculation does not match for the desired baud rate

  - Check fuses (clock source)
  - Check crystal
  - Check UART initialization
- Standard output has not been associated with your "putchar" function

  - `static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM( uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE );`
    where uart_putchar matches `int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);` which is your implementation to send a character.
- ATMEGA128 has a compatibility fuse that disables UART1 if set (default).

  - Shouldn't be a problem since you say you are using UART0, otherwise disable fuse.
- Problem could be on the receiver side

  - Do the UART settings match?
- Problem could be hardware related

  - Double check wiring, PCB and so on.